# why aren't my admob ads showing up in xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

I have been trying to implement google ads in my app, but it is not working, I have tried so many things yet nothing works.
using nuget firebase.ads

here's my ad control code:

```html
 public class AdControlView : View
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty AdUnitIdProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                          nameof(AdUnitId),
                          typeof(string),
                          typeof(AdControlView),
                          string.Empty);

        
      
        
        public string AdUnitId
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(AdUnitIdProperty);
            set => SetValue(AdUnitIdProperty, value);
        }
       
    }
```

my implementation in xaml:

```html
   <ads:AdControlView  
                AdUnitId="{Binding AdUnitId}" 
                BackgroundColor="Red"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="1"
                x:Name="adBanner"
                HeightRequest="50"
                    />
```

and here is my view renderer:

```html
    public class AdViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<AdControlView, AdView>
    {
        public AdViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

       
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AdControlView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null && Control == null)
                SetNativeControl(CreateAdView());
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(AdView.AdUnitId))
                Control.AdUnitId = Element.AdUnitId;
        }

        private AdView CreateAdView()
        {

            var adView = new AdView(Context)
            {
                AdSize = AdSize.Banner,
                AdUnitId = "i have my string id here"
            };

            adView.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FillParent, LayoutParams.FillParent);

            adView.LoadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().Build());
            adView.BringToFront();
            
            return adView;
        }
    }
```

and of course, I have added the code to my manifest file and to my main activity.
nothing seems to work!

Comment: Please open your `AndroidManifest.xml`, If you have these permissions :`ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` and `INTERNET`

Comment: i have them in the manifest.xml

Comment: Follow James' guides ([android](https://montemagno.com/xamarinforms-google-admob-ads-in-android/), [iOS](https://montemagno.com/xamarinforms-google-admob-ads-in-ios/)). You need to recreate your control when AdUnitId changes. Also are you getting any errors in the logs? Have you initialized the plugin in MainActivity/AppDelegate?

Comment: yes I have initialized the plugin, and the control i have is similar to the one in the tutorial u mentioned.